# how to move disc space from rhel-home to rhel-root

Tags: linux, partitioning, rhel8

I need to move disc space from home partition to root partition using `RHEL-8.5`. I am sharing the screen shot below.

[image]

In the above image I have `421G` assign to `rhel-home` partition but I need to move `350G` from `rhel-home` to `rhel-root` partition. Can anybody please provides the steps how to swap this space from home to root ?

Comment: How are you possibly going to move 350G from /home to root if root has only 66G available? Not to mention 70G total.

Comment: I want to extent root partition to around 420GB

Comment: You don't generally need to move any space to root unless you plan on loading more than the currently available 66G of data on root.  You have 764G available on home which can likely be resized safely with gparted if you want to do the move. You would have to look at the partition layout on disk and create space at the end of root to expand it. That said, you have asked on the wrong StackExchange site. This is more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A huge install of almost all programs you can think of rarely exceeds 50G. If you need more data for a website on `/srv` or `/var`, just create a separate partition for it after shrinking `/home` or just add a new disk and create it there.